# How to hide folder directory in Laravel when accessing URL from the address bar

Tags: php, laravel

I want to hide this directory when accessing the url from the address bar for security purpose

I am using Laravel 5+

[image: Sample scenario]

Comment: Add index.html file inside

Comment: Also move your uploads directory outside of public / DocumentRoot - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot

Answer (score 1):

You need to Disable index view. just add this`Options -Indexes` in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the web server rather than PHP/Laravel.

keywords you need to search：

- nginx：`autoindex off`
- apache：`indexes`

Comment: thanks for commenting. I just wanted to ask why it should be configured in the web server rather than in Laravel? thanks!

Comment: Simply because the webserver itself is incharge of serving files, not PHP - So you would need to tell the webserver not to show any files when directly accessing the path via the URL.

Comment: @mauzilla is correct and PHP or other backend languages are just the request logics handler behind the web server which client couldn't aware of directly